# smartctl doesn't seem to work from cronjob

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a cronjob which run a `smartctl` to check the hard drive health - if one drive is failed

The cronjob is setup from webmin, and when the cronjob is run manually from the cronjob manager (pressing "Run now" button) the status returned is `0` (OK), but when the script is run on daily basis from cronjob (every midnight) the status returned is always `1` (one drive is failed)

Could anyone tell my what is going on?!

## command (running from root)

```
php -f /var/www/cronjob.php check_hdd_health
```

## code

```
class Cronjob_check_hdd_health {
    public function __construct(){
        if($this->check_dev('/dev/sda') && $this->check_dev('/dev/sdb')){
            $status = 0;
        }
        else{
            $status = 1;
        }

        // The status is saved in mysql with a timestamp
        echo 'Status: '.$status;
    }

    private function check_dev($dev){
        $status_ok = "=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===\nSMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED";

        $output = shell_exec('smartctl -H '.$dev);

        if(strpos($output, $status_ok) !== false){
            echo "$dev OK!\n";

            return true;
        }
        else{
            echo "$dev ERROR!\n";

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you show what user is executing the shell command ?

Comment: Just a guess: smartctl might have to be executed as super user, so 'sudo smartctl', but in order to make that happen from php the server needs the rights to operate as super user.

Comment: Maybe you should check if smartctl writes something to the logs that might give you an idea if what's going wrong.

Comment: have updated the question with the command.. the user is always `root`

Comment: What happens when you change '$output = shell_exec('smartctl -H '.$dev);' to '$output = shell_exec('sudo smartctl -H '.$dev);' ?

Comment: When adding `sudo` to the command line this error is returned: `sudo: not found`

Comment: You will need to add some more info on your log in order to figure out whats wrong. Ideally you should log what the output of smartctl is which will probably have some kind of error.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that the `sudo` command does not execute either, makes me think that the `PATH` in the `crontab` edited by Webmin is messed up.

You can probably fix the `smartctl` problem by just specifying the `PATH`:

```
shell_exec('/usr/sbin/smartctl -H /dev/sda');
```

but I'd also look at the crontabs; the system crontab can be checked by editing `/etc/crontab`, the `root` crontab with the command (as root)

```
crontab -e
```

You should have some definitions at the top, such as

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin
MAILTO=root
```

You can also add some simple shell diagnostics:

```
print "PATH is: " . getenv('PATH') . "\n";
print "Trying to locate smartctl (hoping 'which' is working)...\n";
print shell_exec('which smartctl 2>&1');
print "Trying to determine user\n";
print shell_exec('/usr/bin/whoami 2>&1');
print shell_exec('/bin/whoami 2>&1');
print shell_exec('whoami 2>&1');
```

Then from root try running `which smartctl` and see whether its path is among the ones returned by `getenv` above.

Answer (score 1):

There's really two possible problems with this.

1. the path to smartctl isn't found.
2. an error occurred and the output isn't being returned.

If the problem is related to #1 then try adding an absolute path to the bin. see example below

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/smartctl -H '.$dev);
```

However the problem is more likely to be caused by #2 in which the output isn't coming back.

This can be resolved by changing this line:

```
$output = shell_exec('smartctl -H '.$dev);
```

to this:

```
$output = shell_exec(sprintf('smartctl -H %s 2>&1', $dev));
```

What this does is redirect STDERR to STDOUT making the output on the error channel visible.

And of course it's possible that both are the problem, in which case you can combine both solutions together.

```
$output = shell_exec(sprintf('/usr/bin/smartctl -H %s 2>&1', $dev));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are omitting the real error because every time the error comes you don't print him to a file, but I imagine this occur because you don't use the absolute path of 'smartctl' command.

```
mlt@slack:~$ sudo /bin/bash -c '/usr/sbin/smartctl -H /dev/sda'
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [x86_64-linux-3.14.24] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

mlt@slack:~$ sudo /bin/bash -c 'smartctl -H /dev/sda'
/bin/bash: smartctl: command not found
```